# what is causing this server error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

standard rails/angular app, server is looking for some kind of img file? I'm not entirely sure.  I should point out that I understand the error is that the server is looking for some kind of route that doesn't or in my opinion, shouldn't exist, so I realize that the error is cause the server wants to find something that doesn't exist, I'm curious what is causing it and how to understand why the app is looking for this, and how to remove the error as well.

server log looks like,

```
Started GET "/%7B%7Blunchers[0].img%7D%7D" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-22 16:34:27 -0800
Started GET "/%7B%7Blunchers[0].img%7D%7D" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-22 16:34:27 -0800
```

and top few lines of the error message

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/%7B%7Blunchers[0].img%7D%7D"):
  actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
```

what should I be considering in this case, at this juncture it doesn't appear to be directly effecting the app itself but I would just assume figure out what it is.  thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a mustache-type template that isn't getting interpreted. Somewhere, there is a tag (probably an img tag) that has it's source set to `{{lunchers[0].img}}`, and rather than the img attribute of the first item in the lunchers array being substituted in that template tag's place, the template is getting served to the browser.

Comment: perfect, that was def it and angular has ng-src used to deal with that.  thanks.

Comment: Holy smokes Batman 'Chuck', how you figured that out I'll never know. I have the exact same issue in an EmberJS application.